# Why I have no list of my domain in Bind in webmin?

Tags: debian, bind, webmin

I have some domains in a server A managed by bind in a webmin and all works fine.

I would like to transfert all of them in a server B in bind in a webmin (the server A is very old).
After transfert, I check config and bind says "all zones loaded".
[My webmin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlfT0.png)
But, in my webmin view, I have no domain listed : what I miss ?

I'm under Debian 11, Bind 9.16, Webmin 2.021

EDIT ; I don't if it's important, but Bind module stay displayed in "un-used Modules" and not in server.

Thanks